# how to get user information from Withings api on grails

Tags: grails, oauth, grails-2.0, scribe

I'm trying to get user information from Withings Api, i've already success login into Withings with Oauth using Scribe library(Java). But there is a problem when i sent request to get user information follow Withings Api document it always return result with error code.

I've tried some way but it didn't work. Can someone help me to solve this problem.

Withings Api http://www.withings.com/en/api#documentation

First i call withings action in WithingsController.groovy to get authentication.

After authenticate success server return access token, in withingsCallback action i get user information.

Result return when get user information is result code of Withings Api

> {"status":2554}

This is my code

WithingsService.groovy

```
def getAuthDetails(callbackUrl) {
    if (!authService) {

        authService = new ServiceBuilder()
                           .provider(WithingsApi.class)
                           .apiKey( grailsApplication.config.oauth.withings.key as String )
                           .apiSecret( grailsApplication.config.oauth.withings.secret as String )
                           .callback( callbackUrl as String )
                           .build();
        }

    Token requestToken = authService.getRequestToken();

    [ authUrl : authService.getAuthorizationUrl(requestToken), requestToken : requestToken ]

}
def getWithingsUserInformation(Token accessToken,String userId){
    String url = 'http://wbsapi.withings.net/user?action=getbyuserid&userid='+userId;
    OAuthRequest request = new OAuthRequest( Verb.POST, url )
    authService.signRequest(accessToken, request)
    Response response = request.send()
    return response
}

def getAccessToken( params, requestToken ){
    requestToken = requestToken as Token
    Verifier verifier = new Verifier( params.oauth_verifier )
    authService.getAccessToken(requestToken, verifier);
}
```

WithingsController.groovy

```
def withings() {
    def authInfo = withingsService.getAuthDetails(createLink(action: 'withingsCallback', controller: 'withings', absolute: 'true'))

    if (authInfo.requestToken)
    {
        session["withings_requestToken"] = authInfo.requestToken
    }

}

def withingsCallback(){
    def accessToken = withingsService.getAccessToken(params, session["withings_requestToken"])
    session["withings_accessToken"] = accessToken
    if(accessToken) {
        def profile 
        String userId = params.userid
        profile =  withingsService.getWithingsUserInformation(accessToken,userId)
       }
   }
```

Comment: Can you show us more info? In typical Oauth flow, you 1) get auth url 2) redirect user to auth url 3) user authenticates and provider calls your servers callback with accesstoken 4) you use the access token. Can you show us, #3 and more specifically, what you're doing in the callback, and finally what is the error you are getting.

Comment: I've already added more detail. Hope you can help me to solve this problem

Answer (score 1):

Unless I'm missing something, it looks like you are not redirecting your user to get the "access token". After you get a request token:

- you then generate a authentication url
- redirect the user to this authentication url
- they will authenticate
- if authentication is successful, provider will call your callback with access token

So your withings action should include:

```
def withings() {
  def authInfo = withingsService.getAuthDetails(createLink(action: ....

  if (authInfo.requestToken)
  {
    session["withings_requestToken"] = authInfo.requestToken
  }

  //are you missing this? 
  redirect(authInfo.authUrl)
}
```

If you're using some type of http debugging/logging, check for the following request after your withings action.

```
https://oauth.withings.com/account/authorize?
oauth_callback=http%3A%2F%2Fexample.com%2Fget_access_token
&oauth_consumer_key=c331c571585e7c518c78656f41582e96fc1c2b926cf77648223dd76424b52b
&oauth_nonce=369f9ceb2f285ac637c9a7e9e98019bd
&oauth_signature=OR9J9iEl%2F2yGOXP2wk5c2%2BWtYvU%3D
&oauth_signature_method=HMAC-SHA1
&oauth_timestamp=1311778988
&oauth_token=5bb105d2292ff43ec9c0f633fee9033045ed4643e9871b80ce586dc1bf945
&oauth_version=1.0
```

Comment: Can you also test for get user information case, because i've already login successful, but i can't get user data.

Comment: @user2264997 You got access to user details? please guide me in this I am struggling like any thing

Comment: "if authentication is successful, provider will call your callback with access token"  This is not the case.  WiThings merely passes back your RequestToken.  You Still need to run one more request, exchanging the RequestToken & Secret for an AccessToken..

Answer (score 0):

Though this is unrelated to the question initially asked, I thought I would post here since this was a common stopping ground for me reaching a `Withings 2554` error.

If updating to the newest version of Withings Api for access token authentication, the [current version of the Withings Api](https://support.withings.com/hc/en-us/articles/360016745358-Deprecating-access-and-refresh-tokens-endpoints) will now also cause this 2554 status code if you do not attach `action: requesttoken` to the access token request body.

Additionally, when pulling apart the response, make sure to drill into the `body` of the payload, since the latest version of the Withings access token api delivers its payload contents differently. This may be a no brainer for those implementing from scratch, but if you are using an oauth library, most of this behavior is abstracted by the library, and it likely won't be anticipating the payload structure to contain the `body` field.

more info here: https://developer.withings.com/api-reference#operation/oauth2-getaccesstoken